# How to unload a level with UnloadSceneAsync after leaving a trigger area?

Tags: triggers, unity-game-engine, scene

I have a game that will have several massive levels that flow right into each other (it's a Metroidvania game), and so I need to unload levels when the character leaves those areas, so that it doesn't crash the game due to using too much memory.

I've already tried:

```
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D coll)
    {
         SceneManager.UnloadScene(sceneIndex);
    }
```

However, I read somewhere that you can't call `UnloadScene` from physics triggers for some reason. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.UnloadScene.html

But they say to use `UnloadSceneAsync`, which doesn't exist. The link in the documentation is broken and my program won't compile when I try to use it.

How to go about this? **How does one unload a scene after the character leaves it?**

EDIT: I've also tried this, but it won't compile:

```
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D coll)
    {
         SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(sceneIndex);
    }
```

Comment: "my program won't compile when I try to use it" Why not post the `UnloadSceneAsync` code that won't compile? You only have code `UnloadScene` in your question.

Comment: @Programmer because it's exactly like the code above but with the word "Async" in it. Added it anyways

Answer (score 0):

The `UnloadSceneAsync` was added in **Unity 5.5** which is still in beta version. The only way to have function available to you is to download the beta version. This is the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync.html) and you can get the latest `Unity 5.5` (*v5.5.0b10* as of writing this) from [here](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta).

You can verify this by going to the Release Note [here](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta/unity5.5.0b10).

Press Ctrl+F then search 'UnloadSceneAsync'. It says:

> - *SceneManager*: Added UnloadSceneAsync API which can be called anytime    unlike UnloadScene.
> - *SceneManager*: UnloadScene has now be marked deprecated and will throw    an exception if called at illegal times. UnloadSceneAsync
>     should be    used instead (762371)